# Worker and daemon thread in java

Tags: java

I have read tutorial concerning background thread(or worker thread) and now I get confused between SwingWorker and daemon thread, are they the same? If i'm writing non GUI application should i create SwingWorker or daemon thread since they both do the job in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of `Thread`s: daemons and non-daemons. The JVM will cease execution when there all non-daemon `Thread`s stop running.

`SwingWorker`s are a utility for performing some time expensive task asynchronously from the Event Dispatch Thread to prevent your GUI from becoming unresponsive. A `SwingWorker` is not a `Thread`, it is a `Runnable` task that can be sumbitted to a `Thread` for execution.

If you are not doing anything with a GUI, use a `Thread`. If you need to perform an action on a separate `Thread` for your GUI, use a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Hi, so the thread that executes submitted Runnable task is daemon or not?

Comment: @FinalIllusion If you call `SwingWorker#execute`, it will be executed on a daemon `Thread`. However, `SwingWorker`s do a lot in the background to synchronize with the Event Dispatch Thread, so unless you are actually performing a task for a GUI, you should not use one.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i would like to know since i don't know how to check whether the thread executing SwingWorker Runnable task is daemon or not.

Comment: @FinalIllusion From the `SwingWorker`'s `doInBackground` you could call `Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()` to check if the `Thread` is a daemon or not. Or you could delve into the source code and discover that the `ThreadPoolExecutor` used internally by `SwingWorker` uses a `ThreadFactory` that creates daemon `Thread`s.

Comment: "The JVM will cease execution when there all non-daemon Threads stop running." That is not true. What you are saying, is this is a necessary but not sufficient condition for the JVM to cease execution.

Comment: @AlexMills What part of it isn't true? Could you clarify your comment?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey - in order to close the JVM it is necessary but not sufficient for all Event Dispatch Threads to close. There is clearly the case where all Event Dispatch Threads finish, but you have some background threads running, and you keep the JVM open in order to run those threads.  Therefore "the JVM will cease execution when there all non-daemon Threads stop running" is a misleading statement.

Comment: @AlexMills Except those other background threads that are running are non-daemon threads. Once every non-daemon thread terminates, including threads that aren't the Event Dispatch Thread, the JVM will begin shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

SwingWorker is a specialized class that eases interacting with user interface. Access to gui components should be done only from special gui thread. SwingWorker has method `done` which is guaranteed to be executed in gui thread, so you can safely update ui.

If you do not interact with swing ui you should use simple Thread. Moreover if you need a few threads its good to look at `ExecutorService` which is a thread pool.