# ensuring that all threads finish before JVM completely terminates

Tags: multithreading, join, jvm, swingworker

Let's say I have a SwingWorker object and it's still in its doInBackground() method. If a user calls system.exit(0)...how do I best ensure that the SwingWorker daemon/worker thread completes? I imagine that I have to do this manually. The best idea I have at the moment is to call join() on all outstanding worker threads in/on the same thread that calls System.exit(0)...is this correct?

AND, if using join() is a good idea...should I use it in some sort of while loop in the case that the thread calling join() has spurious activity?

For instance:

//pseudocode

```
Vector<Thread> threadsThatMustFinishBeforeTerminatingJVM = new Vector<Thread>();

Thread closingThread = new Thread(){


    public void run(){

       for(Thread t: threadsThatMustFinishBeforeTerminatingJVM){

           // closingThread waits for t to finish, (is this *really* safe?)
           t.join();

         }

      System.exit(0);

    }
}

closingThread.start();
```

**Is this at all correct?**

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342767/worker-and-daemon-thread-in-java knowing that when all non-daemon threads complete, the JVM will exit. `return` from `main` will complete the main thread.

Comment: Thanks Lee. But can you point me in the direction to answer my whole question.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=86)

"The System.exit method forces termination of all threads in the Java virtual machine."

If you call system.exit you're basically saying, "exit now, I don't care what's going on." If you want to shut down cleanly you're going to need to set us some kind of coordination/synchronization between your threads.

If your doInBackground method is still active you could wait until it completes before exiting, some synchronization primitive, shared lock, or some such.

You can add some logic in the [done()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done%28%29) method of your SwingWorker that would allow an exit.

The better way is probably to query [getState()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#getState%28%29) on your SwingWorker. It'll return DONE if the task has completed and if so you can exit, otherwise just wait.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But my question is, given that info, what is the best way to wait for all background threads to finish before exiting.